ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration for 3rd Party SDK
I, too, got the "ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration" mail from Apple, mentioning FileTimestamp, UserDefaults and SystemBootTime. I only use UserDefaults directly, FileTimestamp and SystemBootTime are only accessed by 3rd Party SDKs (e.g. Firebase or Alamofire).
Does anyone know which values i have to use? Apple's documentation seems a bit confusing to me.
UserDefaults seems easy: CA92.1, as i am using this directly.
My first guess for SystemBootTime would be 35F9.1, but my app is not using this directly, i would think that i don't need to add this key at all.
FileTimestamp is not used directly either, so i would say 0A2A.1, but then my app is not an SDK. So my next guess would be DDA9.1, or not adding it at all.
Ideas anyone?
Edit says: As far as i can tell, all of my third party SDK come with a privacy manifest.

Do your third party SDKs include a privacy manifest?

@tomerpacific yes, they do

Are you sure there aren't any other SDKs that may not be declaring things using a privacy manifest? Do you mind sharing your pod file?

@tomerpacific Yes, i am, i searched all SDK for the specific methods, i.e. SystemBootTime.systemUptime() is only used by Alamofire, which comes with a privacy manifest.
My question is, what, if anything at all, do i have to put in my manifest?

@Kalie - I wrote an article about privacy manifest recently that might help you out. Without seeing what you actually have and what warnings/errors you got from Apple, it is kind of hard to answer that.

I encounter the exact same problem and share the same concern as you. After creating the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy, I didn't receive the "ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration" email in my latest Apple Store review. Here is what I did:

UserDefaults: CA92.1 without a doubt.

File Timestamp: C617.1 I selected this because in my application, the API is not used directly. After reading the Apple document, I believe the third-party SDK uses this API to identify the user without "the user specifically granted access." So between C617.1 and 3B52.1, I chose the former.

System Boot Time: 35F9.1 To be honest, I am not sure which to select between this and 8FFB.1.

Disk Space: E174.1 In the Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK, I found it chose E174.1. Since I am using this SDK, I chose the same reason.


